# How to create responsive iframe in cross domain?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

We have developed the IFRAME and we have provided it to other users ,the problem is once the particular user uses that IFRAME in there web pages it works properly but once switched to mobile version IFRAME looses its responsiveness to be more specific, content of the IFRAME remains responsive but IFRAME is not getting specific auto height ......??? kindly suggest

```
<iframe src="http://rapidowebs.com/sctimer/my_timer.php?user_id=2"></iframe>ve
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the iframe responsive on every platform, from my experience, you will  need some   Css

First put the following code in your css file

```
.responsive_iframe {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px; 
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
}
.responsive_iframe iframe, 
.responsive_iframe object,
.responsive_iframe embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    max-width:90%;
    max-height:90%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
display:block;

}
```

And then you need to put in something that looks like this

```
<div class='responsive_iframe'><iframe allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0'   src='http://rapidowebs.com/sctimer/my_timer.php?user_id=2'></iframe> </div>
```

Of course, it all depends on the content of your iframe, whether you are planning to put in some object or embed or images and text ...

Comment: Again height issue remains the same in mobile while i am applying your code. Any other suggestion ....? help me out in this .                                   attaching the link as an example kindly check it out in mobile version,height issue remains the same http://krishnanetwork.rapidowebs.com/demoiframe/

Comment: I visited your website with mobile and i saw your problem. The code I gave you is correct BUT it is not working because you did not do it right . The css, style must come before the html div but instead, you put the div before the css. Check a demo [**here**](http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/brouillons-max.php)  . I have tested it with windows phone 8.1

Comment: I have edited the code check it and put the css first before the div and it will work

Comment: thank you ,it helped us in many ways ,looking forward for your support in future .THANK YOU.......It is working now and efficient ....

Comment: @KrunalUpadhyay  
The best way to thank me on this website is by clicking on the top arrow near my correct answer. That will add a plus one to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of unclear.

So I assume you want your `iframe` to be 100% width and 100% height? If thats what you want, you must set its sizes accordingly. Otherwise it doesn't know what you want.

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ra14bbcb/

Comment: thank for answer and sorry for rough English question now read again please help me please